# Trying to do a backspace in textbox.AppendText shows a weird symbol

Tags: c#, .net, text

I have a textbox I am using textbox.AppendText("\b)") and instead of doing a backspace it is showing this symbol just before the bracket that appears.
[Symbol](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L3MZ6.png).
Does anyone know why or have a solution?

Comment: are you trying to get rid of last ")" in that field by making a backslash? \b is still character, but it's not quite representable, so it is displayed as whatever you see.

Comment: I'm trying to get rid of the comma before it. I have used \r and \n before and have had no problems with them.

Comment: because \r\n is represented as new line. it's not moving the caret as such. \b is represented as well by weird symbol. You need to get rid of that comma before you put it in the textbox.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, makes it a bit more difficult but that's just the way it is lol

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`\b` is still character, but it's not quite representable by regular alphabet, so it is displayed as whatever you see.

`\r \n` works well for you as the representation of that is a line break.

What you expecting to have is change the value of the `TextBox` after inserting another character, which is more than just displaying it.

Solution for you would be to modify the string and get rid of it parts that are not needed before you place it in the `TextBox`